# How to change config files in openwrt?

Tags: openwrt

I have to add a `dns` entry in `/etc/config/network`, so I added it in
`package/base-files/files/etc/config/network`. Then did

```
make V=99 package/base-files/clean
make V=99 package/base-files/compile
```

Now it generates an `.ipk` at `bin/x86-eglibc/packages/base/base-files_156-unknown_x86.ipk`. If I install this by `opkg install base-files_156-unkonwn_x86.ipk` the change is not seen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try with the `--force-install` option

Answer (score 0):

`--force-maintainer` should replace existing user configs with the files provided by the new package